# How can I make is so that a function in a shared library can't be called without declaring it static?

Tags: c, haskell, gcc, linker, shared-libraries

The headline may not be entirely clear.

I'm using two source files (one in C, one in Haskell) to compile a shared library (.so). I want some of the functions in one file to be callable from functions in the other file. However, I don't want them to be callable from the program that loads the library.

If I declare them static, the other file's code can't see them.

Is there a way to accomplish this? Does it require configuring the linker or altering the .so file after the fact?

Comment: You can/should do this with a linker _script_ when creating the `.so` But, first, look at `info gcc` and the `-fvisibility=` section. You can also use `__attribute__((visibility(...)))` on each function. For example, if _most_ of the functions are internal (and only a few are part of the public API), you could use a default visibility of `hidden` and add explicit attributes to the public functions

Comment: @CraigEstey This should be an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can/should do this with a linker *script* when creating the `.so`

But, first, look at `info gcc` and the `-fvisibility=` section [included below].

You can also use `__attribute__((visibility("...")))` on each function.

For example, if most of the functions are internal (and only a few are part of the public API), you could use a default visibility of hidden and add explicit attributes to the public functions.

---

**From `info gcc`:**

`-fvisibility=[default|internal|hidden|protected]`

Set the default ELF image symbol visibility to the specified
option--all symbols are marked with this unless overridden within
the code.  Using this feature can very substantially improve
linking and load times of shared object libraries, produce more
optimized code, provide near-perfect API export and prevent symbol
clashes.  It is *strongly* recommended that you use this in any
shared objects you distribute.

Despite the nomenclature, `default` always means public; i.e.,
available to be linked against from outside the shared object.
`protected` and `internal` are pretty useless in real-world usage
so the only other commonly used option is `hidden`.  The default if
`-fvisibility` isn't specified is `default`, i.e., make every
symbol public.

A good explanation of the benefits offered by ensuring ELF symbols
have the correct visibility is given by "How To Write Shared
Libraries" by Ulrich Drepper (which can be found at
https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/)--however a superior solution
made possible by this option to marking things hidden when the
default is public is to make the default hidden and mark things
public.  This is the norm with DLLs on Windows and with
`-fvisibility=hidden` and `__attribute__ ((visibility("default")))`
instead of `__declspec(dllexport)` you get almost identical
semantics with identical syntax.  This is a great boon to those
working with cross-platform projects.

For those adding visibility support to existing code, you may find
`#pragma GCC visibility` of use.  This works by you enclosing the
declarations you wish to set visibility for with (for example)
`#pragma GCC visibility push(hidden)` and `#pragma GCC visibility pop`.  Bear in mind that symbol visibility should be viewed *as
part of the API interface contract* and thus all new code should
always specify visibility when it is not the default; i.e.,
declarations only for use within the local DSO should *always* be
marked explicitly as hidden as so to avoid PLT indirection
overheads--making this abundantly clear also aids readability and
self-documentation of the code.  Note that due to ISO C++
specification requirements, `operator new` and `operator delete`
must always be of default visibility.

Be aware that headers from outside your project, in particular
system headers and headers from any other library you use, may not
be expecting to be compiled with visibility other than the default.
You may need to explicitly say `#pragma GCC visibility push(default)` before including any such headers.

`extern` declarations are not affected by `-fvisibility`, so a lot
of code can be recompiled with `-fvisibility=hidden` with no
modifications.  However, this means that calls to `extern`
functions with no explicit visibility use the PLT, so it is more
effective to use `__attribute ((visibility))` and/or `#pragma GCC visibility` to tell the compiler which `extern` declarations should
be treated as hidden.

Note that `-fvisibility` does affect C++ vague linkage entities.
This means that, for instance, an exception class that is be thrown
between DSOs must be explicitly marked with default visibility so
that the `type_info` nodes are unified between the DSOs.

An overview of these techniques, their benefits and how to use them
is at https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility

Comment: This is a very thorough answer. Thank you very much.